# Add image to a UIView

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am trying to add an Image to a UIView and then add it as a subview on UIViewController.. 
here is my code :

BlowView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BlowView : UIView {
    UIImageView *stone;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *stone;

- (id)init;
@end
```

BlowView.m

```
#import "BlowView.h"

@implementation BlowView

@synthesize stone;

- (id)init {

    UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placard.png"]];
    stone = logoView;
    [logoView release];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placard.png"];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);


    [self initWithFrame:frame];

    return self;
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) { 

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [stone release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

BlowViewController.h

```
@class BlowView;

@interface BlowViewController : UIViewController {
    BlowView *aview;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) BlowView *aview;

-(void)setUpView;
@end
```

BlowViewController.m

```
#import "BlowViewController.h"
#import "BlowView.h"


@implementation BlowViewController

@synthesize aview;

- (void)setUpView {

    // Create the placard view -- its init method calculates its frame based on its image
    BlowView *aView2 = [[BlowView alloc] init];
    self.aview = aView2;
    [aView2 release];
    self.view = self.aview;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}




- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpView];

    aview.center = self.view.center;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [aview release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

can't figure out where I am going wrong. I get no errors.. All I get is a blank WHITE scree. Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

In your first code snippet, you have not add your image to the view, modify below:

```
UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placard.png"]];
stone = logoView;
[logoView release];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placard.png"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);


[self initWithFrame:frame];

// Here add your imageView(stone) to your view as a subview
[self addSubview:stone];

return self;
```

Comment: Surprisingly this didn't work and the app crashed with this "[UIImageView superview]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10167fd0"

Comment: I got a way around this by releasing the logoView instance after adding the subview.. however, I want the entire frame to consist of only the image so that when I do aview.center = CGPointMake(x,y).. it moves the image and not the view as a whole